# Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type TraceWriter

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

Getting the below message when doing right click project -> Debug -> Start New Instance.

> [1/7/2018 6:48:54 AM] A ScriptHost error has occurred[1/7/2018 6:48:54
>   AM] Executed HTTP request: { [1/7/2018 6:48:54 AM]
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'TestFilesIngestJobs.RunScheduleAsync'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type
>   TraceWriter. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding.
>   If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.)
>   make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s)
>   in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(),
>   etc.). [1/7/2018 6:48:54 AM]   "requestId":
>   "dbb282d7-44e2-44b4-907e-877beac9da2d", [1/7/2018 6:48:54 AM] Error
>   indexing method 'MasterDataFilesIngestJobs.RunScheduleAsync' [1/7/2018
>   6:48:54 AM]   "method": "GET",

Comment: And you did *Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.*

Comment: Shouldn't TraceWriter be a full qualified typename?

Comment: Didn’t get you sir

Comment: This is 99% assembly version conflict. Show all NuGet references that you have and which version of .NET/Functions runtime is running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For This to work on your machines, you will have to do two things. Follow the Visual Studio section in this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/)

1. Install Azure-functions-core-tools@core package is installed using
   npm.
2. Create a debug profile and setup as shown below and use that
       profile while launching it from visual studio.

Please find the image below for your help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778925/microsoft-azure-webjobs-host-cannot-bind-parameter-mycontext-to-type-datacont

Answer (score 7):

I got same thing and fixed it by updating Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools.

Note that as per the change list here, support for remote debugging of V2 functions was only enabled in 15.0.31201.0, and was granted a bug fix in 
15.0.40108.0.
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md

So, go into Tools and Extensions, see what version of the Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools you have, and if it's older than 15.0.40108.0, upgrade it.

Comment: Issue is still around in 15.10.2009

Answer (score 2):

got the same error with a brand new Function project in Visual Studio 2017. After getting the prompt from Visual Studio to upgrade Azure Function to v1.0.7 , I got rid of the error