# Error indexing method 'Class.Method' Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type TraceWriter

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-standard-2.0

I have "upgraded" a bunch of my Azure Functions to .netstandard 2.0 and I get the following error:

> Error indexing method 'Class.Method' Cannot bind parameter 'log' to
>   type TraceWriter. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the
>   binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers,
>   etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
>   extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(),
>   config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Following the answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135580/cannot-bind-parameter-log-to-type-tracewriter), I made sure I have the latest version of `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`: it is running 15.0.40322.0. Still, I have the same error.

I know Azure Functions running .netstandard 2.0 is in beta.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it works, turns out I had to:

- Delete the old Function App;
- Create a new one;
- In Function App settings, set the runtime version to beta;
- Publish the Azure Functions.

[image]

Comment: This helped for me as well, only I had to change it from 1 to 2