# Azure functions that are timer based complain about log type

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am having the exact same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135580/cannot-bind-parameter-log-to-type-tracewriter)

But none of the answers works, been googling for a long time and my versions are updated etc and still I get that same error

Code is the sample template

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace NWMPosNGPimFeeder
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

Versions of host etc is as follows including the actual error

```
[21/5/2018 2:03:29 AM] Host has been specialized
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
[21/5/2018 2:03:29 AM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\MattDouhan\source\repos\NWMPosNGPimFeeder\NWMPosNGPimFeeder\bin\Debug\net461\host.json'
[21/5/2018 2:03:29 AM] Host configuration file read:
[21/5/2018 2:03:29 AM] {
[21/5/2018 2:03:29 AM] }
[21/5/2018 2:03:30 AM] Loaded custom extension 'BotFrameworkConfiguration'
[21/5/2018 2:03:30 AM] Loaded custom extension 'SendGridConfiguration'
[21/5/2018 2:03:30 AM] Loaded custom extension 'EventGridExtensionConfig'
[21/5/2018 2:03:31 AM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[21/5/2018 2:03:31 AM] Starting Host (HostId=desktop7cks1do-1972353084, Version=1.0.11232.0, ProcessId=2668, Debug=False, Attempt=0)
[21/5/2018 2:03:31 AM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[21/5/2018 2:03:31 AM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type TraceWriter. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
[21/5/2018 2:03:31 AM] Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'
```

Comment: Could you offer some info like your function app version(v1 or v2), the cli, host version. See example>https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuOFu.png

Comment: Added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem locates at the old function cli VS is using.

> Version=1.0.11232.0

It means the cli version is `1.0.4`. This old version does cause your issue but it has already been fixed in new ones.

Check your `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools` version.

Latest extension `15.0.40502.0`, will make VS use cli `1.0.4` if VS fails to download new version cli. This downloading process is in background and seems no explicit warning. See [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/807).

**Solution**

I recommend you to delete `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools` folder and restart your VS to download it again.

When we create a function app, we can see tip on the dialog that `Making sure all templates are up to date...`

[image]

Wait for a while, we can see the tip changes as

[image]

If it doesn't change after 3m(time to download 200M files on your side), check `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.0.12.1` folder to see whether it's empty. If it's empty, which means downloading can't be done through VS. We have to do it manually.

You can find download link of cli, itemTemplates and projectTemplates in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\feed.json`.

You can refer to `1.0.10` folder to build similar folder structure.

Comment: I am a little bit confused sorry, I have Microsoft.net.sdk.functions 1.0.13 are you saying another nuget package? O am not sure exactly how to check what you are referring to

Comment: @MattDouhan You mean not sure how to check `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`  version?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't matter, I deleted the folder and restarted and vola after downloading the new version it works jut fine :)